# Smooth Submanifolds of $\mathbb{RP}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $ M=\{[z_0,z_1,z_2, z_3] \in \mathbb{RP}^3 | (z_0-z_3)^2+az_1^2=0\}$, where $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $M$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{RP}^3$ of dimension $2$ when $a=0$, but not if $a\ne0.$

So far:

If $a=0 \implies z_0=z_3$, so we are looking at the subspace $N\subset M$, where $N=\{[z_0,z_1,z_2, z_0] \in \mathbb{RP}^3 \}\cong \{[z_0,z_1,z_2] \} \cong \mathbb{RP}^2$, and $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is a smooth manifold of dimension 2.

If $a\ne 0$, I'm not really sure how to proceed. I tried to do as I did above and got $N=\{[z_0, \pm (-a)^{-1/2}(z_0 -z_3),z_2, z_3] \in \mathbb{RP}^3 \}$.

Note: I initially tried using parameterizations and Regular Value Thm for the first part, but 0 is not a regular value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the case where $a$ is negative, just say $-1$ for ease, you get, $$z_0-z_3+z_1=0$$ or $$z_0-z_3-z_1=0$$ the union of two planes, so their points of intersection are not smooth.

If $a$ is positive, say $1$, then you have 
$$z_0=z_3$$and $$z_1=0$$ this seems to be the intersection and its a line, so it seems to me to be smooth ? But its dimension is $1$, so maybe this is what was meant.

Comment: Thanks, so when $a$ is positive we are looking at $ \{ [z_0,0,z_2,z_2] \}\cong \{[z_0,z_2] \}\cong \mathbb{RP}^1$? I'm still trying to make sense of what you said for $a$ negaitive when we look at it in $\mathbb{RP}^3$...

Comment: Yes thats right about the negative. For the positive it is like having two planes in three dimensional space. They intersect and at these point of intersection there is no well defined tangent space.

Comment: Okay, I think I see that...I map out of proj space using the std chart $\phi([z_0,z_0-z_3,z_2,z_3])=z_3^{-1}(z_0,z_0-z_3,z_2)$ and $\phi([z_0,-(z_0-z_3),z_2,z_3])=z_3^{-1}(z_0,z_0-z_3,z_2)$ and get these two intersecting planes in R3 that are not a smooth submanifold...?